# Why the progress bar hang while calling web service?

Tags: blackberry

I am making a web service call .I am showing progress bar untill web service response not come .But It hang (stop increment the value) or some time it will show error .?
can we overcome this problem .

here is my code

```
    public class MyApp extends UiApplication
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
            // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
            MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
            theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
        }



        public MyApp()
        {

            MyScreen.progressBar=new ProgressBar("Loading data", 100, 90);
            MyScreen.progressBar.start();
            // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
            pushScreen(new MyScreen());
        }    
    }

====================================================================



        public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
        {
            public static ProgressBar progressBar;

            /**
             * Creates a new MyScreen object
             */
            public MyScreen()
            {        
                // Set the displayed title of the screen       
                setTitle("MyTitle");
                add(new LabelField("Test"));

        for (int i = 0; i <10000; i++) {
            System.out.println("i");

        }



                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if ( ProgressBar.popup.isDisplayed()){
                     ProgressBar.popup.close();
                     ProgressBar.remove();

                }


        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SecondScreen()) ;
            }
        });
            }
        }
    ===========================================================

        public class SecondScreen extends MainScreen {
            protected void onDisplay() {

                ConnectJsonWebService conjsonTocService = new ConnectJsonWebService();

                conjsonTocService.jsonResult("http://50.57.145.165:8080/FirstGroupRailApps/jservices/rest/"+"a/"+"destinationdashboard"+"?crsCode="+"PAD"+"&device_pin="+Integer.toHexString(DeviceInfo.getDeviceId()));
                System.out.println("**************Destination Response**********************"+conjsonTocService.response);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDisplay();
            }

            public SecondScreen() {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
        }


    =====================================================================
    package mypackage;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //File Name                  :       ProgressBar.Java
    //Created On                 :       22 April 2010
    //Created By                 :       Ekansh Srivastava
    //Purpose                    :       This source file contains class which is a thread used for 
    //                                 showing cinnecting PopUpWindow after LOGIN 
    //Change History
    //Date                    Modified By                     Change
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.GaugeField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.PopupScreen;
    import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Class Name      :       ProgressBar
    //Created On      :       22 April 2010
    //Created By      :       Ekansh Srivastava
    //Purpose         :       This class is a thrad which is used for Displaying Connecting PopUp after LogIn
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class ProgressBar extends Thread {

    private int maximum, timeout;

    private static boolean useful;

    public static PopupScreen popup;

    public static GaugeField gaugeField;
    public static LabelField gaugetitleField;

    private  ButtonField stopBtn; 
    int iterations = 0;
    public static ProgressBar instance;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //      Function Name           :       ProgressBar (Constructor)
    //      Created On              :       22 April 2010
    //      Created By              :       Ekansh Srivastava
    //      Input Parameters        :       String title, int maximum, int timeout
    //      Output                  :       void
    //      Purpose                 :       Executes the class, set the values and displays the Progress Bar
    //      Change History
    //      Date                Modified By                             Change
    //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public ProgressBar(String title, int maximum, int timeout) 
    {
    try
    {
        this.maximum = maximum;
        this.timeout = timeout;

        VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        HorizontalFieldManager buttonManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(); 
        popup = new PopupScreen(manager){
            public void sublayout(int width, int height){

                super.sublayout(width,height);
                setPosition(12,2*Display.getHeight()/3);
                }

        };
        gaugeField = new GaugeField(null, 1, maximum, 1, GaugeField.NO_TEXT);
        stopBtn = new ButtonField("CANCEL")
                    {
                        protected boolean navigationClick(int status,int time)
                        {
                            remove();
                            onClose();
                            return true;                         
                        }
                    };

      //  Font fon = Utility.getsFont(1);

       // buttonManager.add(new SeparatorFieldClass(65,0));        
       // stopBtn.setFont(fon);
                    gaugetitleField=new LabelField(title,Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        manager.add(gaugetitleField);
        manager.add(gaugeField);
        manager.add(buttonManager);

        instance = this;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in ProgressBAr : ProgressBar()" + e.toString());
    }

    }

    public void run() 
    {
    try
    {
        useful = true;

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(popup);
                }
            });



        while (useful) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeout);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    if (++iterations > maximum)
                        iterations = 1;
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                              gaugeField.setValue(iterations);
                        }
                    });

            }

            if (popup.isDisplayed()) {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(popup);
                            }
                    });
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in ProgressBAr : run()" + e.toString());
    }
    }


    /* To remove Progress Bar*/
    public static synchronized void remove() 
    {
    useful = false;
    }

    public static ProgressBar getInstance()
    {
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new ProgressBar("Connecting..",100,50);
    }

    return instance;
    } 

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //      Function Name           :       onClose
        //      Created On              :       22 April 2010
        //      Created By              :       Ekansh Srivastava
        //      Input Parameters        :       None
        //      Output                  :       Void
        //      Purpose                 :       This method is remove Progress Bar and Close the Application
        //      Change History
        //      Date                Modified By                             Change
        //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public boolean onClose() 
    {
    try
    {
       Dialog.inform("Application will exit");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in ProgressBar : onClose() "+e.toString());
    } 

    return true;
    }       

    }



================================================
package mypackage;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;


import net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class ConnectJsonWebService extends Thread {


     private String url;
     public String response;
     private String myinterface = ";deviceside=true";

      public void run() {
             HttpConnection conn = null;
             InputStream in = null;
             int code;

       try {


          conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(this.url + NetworkAvailabilityCheck.getUrl(), Connector.READ);
             conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
             code = conn.getResponseCode();

             if (code == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                 in = conn.openInputStream();
                 byte[] buffer = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in);
                 this.response = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");


                 if (in != null){
                     in.close();
                 }
                 if (conn != null){
                     conn.close();
                 }
             }

         } catch (Exception e) {
            Dialog.inform(e.toString());
         }
    }  

    public String jsonResult(String url){
      this.url = url;
    //  this.start();
     this.run();
      return response;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some other oddities in this code, but the most significant one is this:

```
public String jsonResult(String url){
  this.url = url;
//  this.start();
 this.run();
  return response;
 }
```

this.run() executes the connection code immediately, which is probably not what you want, since you are running on the Event Thread, so in effect you are blocking the Event Thread and thus all Ui updates. Networking code is blocking and so should not be executed on the Event Thread.  For more on this see here:

[What is the Event Thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/What-is-the-Event-Thread/ta-p/446865)

[Blocking operation not permitted on Event Thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blocking-operation-not-permitted-on-event-dispatch-thread/ta-p/444865)

So instead of running your Thread, you should start it  Search for more on using Java Threads, for example, see here:

[introduction-to-java-threads](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html)

If you do run this as non blocking, then you will get to get the response back asynchronously, so you need to look at something like the Observer pattern.

All of this has been covered numerous times on this and other forums, so I also suggest you look for other samples of code that people have developed specifically for BlackBerry, that download and process pieces of data.

**Update**

You asked:
"can you make me a demo so that I will understand the basic of that"

I am not sure how I could create something that was any better than the many samples already out there, including the ones on the BB site itself, like this:

[Network API](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/network_api_1984363_11.html)

And the link you supplied

[Implement Simplified Observer Pattern to Avoid BlackBerry UI Lockup](http://dftr.ca/?p=235)

seems like a pretty good example using the Observer Pattern,  And I see you have found some samples I wrote which cover the same sort of ground.  I think the appropriate action for you is to implement one of the samples as is, work through the code and try to understand it.

The Event Thread is not easy, nor is Networking, I don't think anyone can wave a magic wand and get you to understand it.  I think you need to work on this yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: can you change this on my code ..Actually Using that example I will understand

Comment: can you make me a demo so that I will understand the basic of that

Comment: can you use this on my example http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Please-Wait-or-Progress-Bar-Code/m-p/433456